# What can I do if my Google ADmob app-ads.txt tab only shows 1 app despite having 2 apps with different websites?

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-console, package-name

My ADmob app-ads.txt tab in the `All applications` tab only shows me 1 app. But I have another app that has a different website with the app-ads.txt and it doesn't even show up as an app on the site. I added the website to the app in the Google Play Console.

Also, could it be a problem that I misspelled my package name in build and instead of com.CompanyName.AppName it is comCompanyName.Appname?

My problem is that my app doesn't even show up. It doesn't say that app-ads.txt wasn't found on website. It doesn't show the app. For example: MyApp1 has it's app-ads.txt at myapp1example.com/app-ads.txt and Admob says: "Found it". And MyApp2 (that is also available on the Play Store) and has a website with the app-ads.txt like: myapp2example.com/app-ads.txt, But Admob only shows MyApp1 and MyApp2 don't even show up.

I followed Google's step by step guide. I waited the at least 24 hours. Even more. I tried to look up the problem but no matter how I phrased the search answer never showed up. I tried to find people who had similiar problems but didn't find any that could help. I can only find help for how to post the app-ads.txt on a website. But I already did it the same way for both of the apps and they both have the website linked in the Play Store.